# changing a MySQL query to a drupal query any ideas

Tags: database

**I'm trying to change the following query to a drupal db_query:**

```
SELECT first_name, SUBSTR(first_name,1,3) AS firstname_substr FROM civicrm_contact WHERE id != 'NULL' ;
```

**I have tried this, but its not working:**

```
$firstname_substr = $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(cc.first_name,1,3)','cc.firstname_substr');
```

**Below is the function I am trying to add it to:**

```
function search_pcp($name, $from = 0, $count = 5){

  $query = db_select('civicrm_pcp', 'pcp');
  $query -> join('civicrm_contribution_page','cp', 'pcp.page_id = cp.id');
  $query -> join('civicrm_contact','cc','pcp.contact_id = cc.id');
  $query -> addJoin('LEFT OUTER','civicrm_entity_file','cef', 'cef.entity_id = pcp.id');
  $query -> addJoin('LEFT OUTER','civicrm_file','cf', 'cef.file_id = cf.id');
  $query -> condition('pcp.is_active','1','=');
  $query -> condition('cp.is_active','1','=');  

  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_or->condition('cc.first_name',  $name, 'like');
  $db_or->condition('cc.last_name',  $name, 'like');

  **//$db_or->condition($firstname_substr, $name);**

  $query -> condition($db_or);

  return $query->execute();

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, where are you placing that code into the function?  You might complete the serach_pcp function showing where you have tried to put the code.

Comment: I put $firstname_substr just above line: $db_or = db_or();   Then I added this line $db_or->condition($firstname_substr, $name); just below $db_or->condition('cc.last_name', $name, 'like');     Sorry I'm a complete newbie!!! have been trying to figure it out all day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to change

```
$firstname_substr = $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(cc.first_name,1,3)','cc.firstname_substr');
```

to

```
$query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(cc.first_name,1,3)','firstname_substr');
```

and

```
$db_or->condition($firstname_substr, $name);
```

to

```
$db_or->condition('firstname_substr', '%'. db_like($name) . '%', 'like');
```

So it will look like this:

```
function search_pcp($name, $from = 0, $count = 5){

  $query = db_select('civicrm_pcp', 'pcp');
  $query->join('civicrm_contribution_page','cp', 'pcp.page_id = cp.id');
  $query->join('civicrm_contact','cc','pcp.contact_id = cc.id');
  $query->addJoin('LEFT OUTER','civicrm_entity_file','cef', 'cef.entity_id = pcp.id');
  $query->addJoin('LEFT OUTER','civicrm_file','cf', 'cef.file_id = cf.id');
  $query->condition('pcp.is_active','1','=');
  $query->condition('cp.is_active','1','=');

  // changed cc.firstname_substr to just firstname_substr
  $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(cc.first_name,1,3)','firstname_substr');

  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_or->condition('cc.first_name',  $name, 'like');
  $db_or->condition('cc.last_name',  $name, 'like');

  // corrected the condition statement
  $db_or->condition('firstname_substr', '%' . db_like($name) . '%', 'like');

  $query -> condition($db_or);

  return $query->execute();

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I actually didnt even have to use a substring. all I required was your condition above -   $db_or->condition('firstname_substr', '%' . db_like($name) . '%', 'like'); replacing the 'firstname_substr' with cc.first_name. That allowed me to search using any amount of letters, if that makes sense. Thanks Alot!!!